# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite' when try to call django-admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

when I run the command `django-admin collectstatic` in terminal i'm getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'
```

it even appears at the end of the list `django-admin` commands help

```
Type 'django-admin help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.
Available subcommands:

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    runserver
    sendtestemail
    shell
    showmigrations
    sqlflush
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver
Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: No module named 'mysite').
```

#### The project structure

```
myProject
    |
    +----mysite
    |        |
    |        +----settings.py
    |        +----wsgi.py
    |        +----urls.py
    |
    |
    +----todo (app)
    |
    +----accounts(app)
    |
    +----myvenv
```

#### setting.py

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
```

#### wsgi.py

```py
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `django-admin collectstatic` use this command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

refer to this topic https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-and-manage-py

Answer (score 0):

Create `__init__.py` file inside myside dir and myproject

Comment: i don't think `__init__.py` was missing in `mysite` folder because the command `django-admin startproject mysite` will scaffold the the minimum project structure with default files including `__init__.py` unless it's was accidentally deleted.

Comment: it's already had  initialized in mysite folder, but not in myProject folder